# 2D array even odd java

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have to segregate the even and odd numbers in a 2D array in java in two different rows (even in row 1 and odd in row two). I have included the output of my code  bellow here is what I have:

```
class TwoDimensionArrays {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int sum = 0;
        int row = 2;
        int column = 10;
        int[][] iArrays = new int[row][column]; 

        for(int rowCount = 0; rowCount < iArrays.length /*&& rowCount % 2 == 0*/; rowCount++) {
            for(int columnCount = 0; columnCount < iArrays[0].length /*&& columnCount % 2 != 0*/; columnCount++) {
                if(columnCount % 2 != 0 /*&& rowCount % 2 == 0*/) {
                iArrays[rowCount][columnCount] = columnCount + 1;

                }   


            }


        }

    System.out.println("The array has " + iArrays.length + " rows");
    System.out.println("The array has " + iArrays[0].length + " columns");

    for(int rowCount = 0; rowCount < iArrays.length; rowCount++) {
        for(int columnCount = 0; columnCount < iArrays[0].length; columnCount++) {
            System.out.print(iArrays[rowCount][columnCount] + " ");
            sum += iArrays[rowCount][columnCount];
        }
    System.out.println();
    }
    System.out.println("The sum is: " +sum);
    }
}
//OUTPUT//
/*The array has 2 rows
The array has 10 columns
0 2 0 4 0 6 0 8 0 10 
0 2 0 4 0 6 0 8 0 10 
The sum is: 60*/
```

Can anyone lend a hand?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Where are you stuck? I think that kind of information is required here.

Comment: Sorry. Here is the output.
//OUTPUT//
/*The array has 2 rows
The array has 10 columns
0 2 0 4 0 6 0 8 0 10 


0 2 0 4 0 6 0 8 0 10
The Second row should have 1 3 5 7 9 instead of what is currently displayed.

Comment: Well, that is kind of yeah, the result of this task but, _where are you stuck_? In other words, when you put a breakpoint somewhere in your code and step through it, where is code missing or where do the code do something you don't want it to do?

Comment: What is this task trying to do? Did you mean to generate the input in such a way that all the numbers are even?

Comment: I think the problem is in the initialization of the array (the first two for loops). The code works but only partially. It copies the contents of the first row into the second row.

Comment: I think he has an array of mixed digits in the beginning. The result should be that those are divided into an array with even digits and an array with odd digits.

Comment: @Steve K 
What I am trying to do is put the first 10 even numbers in the first row of a 2D array and the first 10 odd numbers in the second row.

Comment: @mattias 
Correct. I need to sort the array into even and odd numbers

Comment: @Emil no, the initialization doesn't copy the contents of the first row into the second row. In both rows, it sets the value to the column number + 1 if the column index isn't divisible by 2. The values of every even column are thus 0, and every odd column are also even since you're adding 1 to them. If you do it the other way, and check for even columns as you've commented out, then your even columns will be odd numbers, while your odd columns are 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of passing over the list twice try this:

```
for(int v = 0; v < 20; v++) {
    iArrays[v % 2][(int)v/2] = v;
}
```

This will set `iArrays` to:

```
[[0,2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18],
 [1,3,5,7,9,11,13,15,17,19]]
```

What is happening is the `row` is being set to the remainder of `v % 2` (`0` if `v` is even, `1` if `v` is odd) and the `col` is being set to the corresponding index (with the cast to `int` to drop any fraction).  You can even generalize it like this:

```
public static int[][] group(int groups, int size){
    int[][] output = new int[groups][size];
    for(int value = 0; value < (groups*size); value++) {
        output[value % groups][(int)value/groups] = value;
    }
    return output;
}
```

Then a call to `group(2, 10)` will return:

```
[[0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18], [1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 17, 19]]
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, one solution is to iterate the array from `0` to `COLUMN` and set each successive slot to two plus the previous slots value (starting with 0 for even and 1 for odd). Like,

```
public static void main(String arg[]) {
    final int ROW = 2;
    final int COLUMN = 10;
    int[][] iArrays = new int[ROW][COLUMN];
    for (int i = 0; i < COLUMN; i++) {
        iArrays[0][i] = (i > 0) ? iArrays[0][i - 1] + 2 : 0; // 0,2,4,6...
        iArrays[1][i] = (i > 0) ? iArrays[1][i - 1] + 2 : 1; // 1,3,5,7...
    }
    System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(iArrays));
}
```

Output is

```
[[0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18], [1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 17, 19]]
```